# Nx e2e cypress runner: values from cypress.env.json entries not overwriting same entries in cypress.json env object

Tags: angular, cypress, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have an Nx powered angular project and am facing an issue where values supplied in a `cypress.env.json` file do not override corresponding entries in the `env` object of the `cypress.json` configuration file

This is the first time I have attempted this with an Nx powered project, in a non Nx angular project this behaviour works out of the box with Cypress.

### Steps to Reproduce

In an e2e application's `cypress.json` file, add an `env` object property with an empty value assigned to a some variable name property:

```json
// cypress.json
"env": {
  "MY_VAR": "abc"
}
```

Create a cypress.env.json file at the same location as cypress.json with a key matching the env variable name just added to cypress.json:

```json
// cypress.env.json
{
  "MY_VAR": "xyz"
}
```

Now create a simple test suite to assert that the env variable is equal to the value in the `cypress.env.json`

```js
// create a test spec containing this
describe('When reading the MY_VAR env variable', () => {
  it('should match the value in our cypress.env.json file', () => {
    cy.log('MY_VAR = ' + Cypress.env('MY_VAR'))
    expect(Cypress.env('MY_VAR')).to.eq('xyz');
  });
});
```

When running this suite via the nx e2e runner (`nx run app-name:e2e`) an assertion error will be thrown:

```
AssertionError: expected 'abc' to equal 'xyz'
      + expected - actual

      -'abc'
      +'xyz'
```

I have verified the behaviour works as expected with a non Nx angular\cypress project of mine - its worth noting the `cypress.env.json` in my other project is at the root of the project along with the `cypress.json` file.

I tried locating the cypress.env.json file in my Nx project at the root, instead of inside `apps/my-app-e2e/src` next to the `cypress.json`, but this made no difference.

Am I misunderstanding how to achieve this via Nx?

Project dependencies are as follows:

```
Node : 12.16.3
  OS   : darwin x64
  npm  : 6.14.5

  nx : 12.9.0
  @nrwl/angular : 12.9.0
  @nrwl/cli : 12.9.0
  @nrwl/cypress : 12.9.0
  @nrwl/devkit : 12.9.0
  @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx : 12.9.0
  @nrwl/express : Not Found
  @nrwl/jest : 12.9.0
  @nrwl/linter : 12.9.0
  @nrwl/nest : 12.9.0
  @nrwl/next : Not Found
  @nrwl/node : 12.9.0
  @nrwl/nx-cloud : 12.3.13
  @nrwl/react : Not Found
  @nrwl/schematics : Not Found
  @nrwl/tao : 12.9.0
  @nrwl/web : Not Found
  @nrwl/workspace : 12.9.0
  @nrwl/storybook : 12.9.0
  @nrwl/gatsby : Not Found
  typescript : 4.3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a basic nx workspace, added your config and test and it worked ok.

[image]

- npx create-nx-workspace --preset=angular
- node v 15.1.0
- npm v 7.5.6
- nx e2e testng-e2e --watch

Comment: Can you push your code somewhere please?

Comment: It's the bog standard app created from the angular template. The NodeJS, npm, and command to run are all different to yours (the only differences). I mentioned them as a place to start checking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 3 Different Ways:

**Method 1.** Configuring Cypress To Run On Different Environments Using baseUrl in cypress.json

**Method 2:** Setup Multiple Environments in Cypress With Separate Cypress Configuration Files for Each Environment

**Method 3:** Run Your Cypress Tests in Multiple Environments With Cypress Environment Variable and Custom Utility Class

From `Project` Folder Root > Navigate to `cypress` folder > open `support` folder.

Create a new Typescript file (alternatively you can create a Javascript file as well) with name `utility.ts`.

```
//utility.ts
export class Utility {
getBaseUrl() {
let envi = Cypress.env('ENV'); //Get the value of evnironment variable i.e ENV
if (envi == 'production') //Check the value
return "https://www.proudction-website.com"; //return desired url
else if (envi == 'staging')
return "https://staging-website.com";
else if (envi == 'qa')
return "http://qa-website.com";
  }
}
```

Create a Spec File and Use the Environment URL
We have created our own utility function, which will return the environment-specific URLs. Now, let’s create a Cypress spec file.

In the Spec file, you can call the `getBaseUrl()` function by importing the `Utility` class like below

```
//my.spec.ts
​
//Import Utility from support folder
import { Utility } from "../../../support/utility"
​
//Call getBaseUrl() to get environment specific url value
const url = new Utility().getBaseUrl();
​
describe('Verify Environment Config' + url, () => {
it('Verify Environment', () => {
cy.visit(url); //use url variable
});
});
```

Run your Cypress test on the production environment using the below command:

```
npx cypress run --env ENV="production"
```

Run your  Cypress test on the staging environment using the below command:

```
npx cypress run  --env ENV="staging"
```

Courtesy:https://softans.com/configure-multiple-environments-in-cypress/